# Generate binary signal and convert to integer in Matlab

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

I am going to test an algorithm and need a test signals.

My first test signal is a binary signal of 1 or -1. I was thinking about how to implement such a sequence in matlab and wrote this:

```
binary_data = rand(1,M) > 0.5;
b = 2.*binary_data - 1;
```

My next step is:

```
dataInMatrix = reshape(b,length(b)/k,k); % reshape data into binary k-arrays, k=log2(M), M -size of signal constelation
dataSymbolsIn = bi2de(dataInMatrix);
```

error:
`Expected input number 1, binary vector b, to be nonnegative.`

How to convert such binary sequence to integer if i need create symbols?

EDIT 1.

Guys, I have generated a test signal and it look like this:

[image]

- i generate a sequence 1 or -1
- use a raised cosine filter

How can I get a blue lines...show samples ( digital signal)?

Comment: Hi. This is not a signal processing but a pure matlab programming question (Stackoverflow might be a better place), and honestly, it reads like you really should start with the tutorial that comes with matlab.

Comment: @Marcus Muller. Ali23's question certainly *is* a signal processing question! He needs help generating digital test signals. Rather than belittling Ali23, you should try to help him.

Comment: Hi @RichardLyons you're right, this question has come a long way since it was stated (back then it was really just containing `a=ones(1,N):
signal = [ a -a a -a];`, and that really told me that prior to tackling the signal processing, Ali23 needed to get familiar with the tools :) I didn't mean to belittle!

Comment: Hi @Marcus Muller. Thanks for your comment. I didn't intend to sound "too strong". I merely want the very smart guys on this web site to be as friendly and helpful as they can be.

Comment: @RichardLyons Thank you for the kind words; I was harsher in my wording than I intended to be, and you very graciously helped both Ali and me a bit here – so, thanks you, and I really think I could have handled that slightly better, and you certainly didn't come across too strongly :)

Comment: Hallo Marcus. Kein Problem. Ich hoffe, Sie und ich sind jetzt Freunde.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Unfortunately, you are always harsh in your wording, I see the majority of your comments are little bit "aggressive" specially when you don't know the answer. You usually evaluate the question itself instead of trying to help to get the answer.  I am really sorry to say that , but I hope that will help in improving the quality of reply.  please take it in a friendly way, I want just to advise you to take care of that point

Comment: @Zeyad_Zeyad I'm thankful for getting such feedback, but honestly, click on the history of this quesiton, and compare the "now" state with the "back then" state. If my original comment helped foster this change, I'm still sorry about the harshness, but the effect was positive.

Answer (score 2):

@Ali23. If by "How can I get a blue lines?" you mean how to generate samples of the your red curve, try the following:

m = [1, -1, -1, 1 1, -1]; m = [m m m m];

N = length(m);

M = 10; mup=zeros(1,N*M); mup(1:M:N*M)=m;  % oversample by M

h = hamming(M);                     % blip pulse of width M

x = filter(h,1,mup);     % convolve pulse shape with 'm' data

t = 1/M:1/M:length(x)/M;

figure(1), subplot(2,1,1), plot(0:0.1:0.9,h)

subplot(2,1,2), plot(t,x)

In the above I used a simple hamming sequence rather than the impulse response of a RRC filter. (You should use the impulse response of a RRC filter.) The key point here is that you have to upsample (zero stuffing) the 'm' sequence before you apply it to the filter.

Answer (score 1):

@Ali23. your 'binary_data = rand(1,M) > 0.5;' command generates "logical" data. Try using  'binary_data  = int8(rand(1,M));' and see if that helps you.